# TypeError: Structtype 'int' -Pyspark in databricks

Tags: pyspark

I'm getting  TypeError: StructType can not accept object 3000 in type <class 'int'>

Code below. I can't see why 3000 can't be used as an integer? Am I doing something wrong?

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField("pull_date",TimestampType(),True),StructField("Tot_Crdts",IntegerType(),True),StructField("Sum_Crdts",FloatType())])
data = [current_timestamp() , 3000, 1.00]

DFQuant = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data should be the list of 3-tuple. And the `current_timestamp()` *function* is not working outside of the dataframe, so I have changed to use the datetime package.

```
import sys
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("pull_date", TimestampType(), True), 
    StructField("Tot_Crdts", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Sum_Crdts", FloatType())
])
data = [(datetime.datetime.now(), 3000, 1.00)]

DFQuant = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
DFQuant.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+---------+---------+
|pull_date                 |Tot_Crdts|Sum_Crdts|
+--------------------------+---------+---------+
|2021-06-23 13:57:10.363901|3000     |1.0      |
+--------------------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thx!! I see i was missing the paranthesis. works now